# Follow distinct transform with ParDo - Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Is it a good idea to use ParDo immediately after Distinct? What's happening is that, the Extract First Element step in Distinct transform is working in parallel with the following ParDo and subsequent transforms. The pipeline for some odd reason has slowed down. Should I wait for the distinct to finish and then move on by creating a dummy transform in between like side-input?

Please let me know...

Code Snippet:

```
p.apply(TextIO.read().from("gs://"))
.apply(Distinct.<String>create())
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn...))
.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn...))
.apply(SpannerIO.write()...)
```

Comment: Can you post some code to show what your pipeline looks like, and the behavior you're seeing? It's hard to understand by just your description

Comment: @Pablo I've updated the post with a snippet. So my question was shall I wait for the Distinct transform to finish first? Because when things run in parallel, I observed that the pipeline gets a bit slow. However I'm not really sure of that. Hence needed some guidance.